# Get columns from excel file and plot them

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm new to python, and I have this assignment I have to deliver soon.
I have a .xlsx file that I've imported with `pandas`. It's a file from my workplace which tells us the day (mon - sat), time (from 10 am - 8 pm), sales per hour, visiting customers and customers that actually bought from the store (5 rows, 65 col). How can I get the total sales from each of the days? I tried to get the sum from monday by writing the cols from that day, but it wasn't accurate.

```
monday = (data['Sales per hour'][1:12].sum())
```

Is there a better way to sum the data from monday without having to write down the cols `[1:12].sum())`?

Here is a pic of the file I'm using. I want to get the total sum for each of the days and plot them into a histogram. I's also like to plot a comparison histogram between visiting customers and buying customers.

[The file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvQ9N.png)

Comment: Can you show us some example-rows that you're working with, as well as a mock-up of how you want the date represented?

Comment: Please add the data of the file as actual text inside of the question. No one will copy down your data manually from that picture to try to help you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#You can try Pandas's Group by to resolve your issue

First, rename the column for better use remove blank space from the name

```
data.rename(columns = {'Sales per hour':'Sales_per_hour'}, inplace = True) 
Daywise_Data=data.groupby('Day').Sales_per_hour.sum().reset_index()
```

This will give you day-wise data into a separate data frame which can be used further to plot the histogram.